# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error angular universe

Tags: angular, angular8, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

When I try to run my Angular universal app using npm run serve:ssr it displays the below error in a terminal window.

```
Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000
ERROR [NetworkError]
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
at resolvePromise (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:1016:31)
at resolvePromise (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:973:17)
at D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:1077:17
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:587:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server\main.js:84552:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:586:60)
at Zone.runTask (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:359:47)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:765:35)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:666:21)
at Server.ZoneTask.invoke (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:651:48) {
rejection: [NetworkError],
promise: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
__zone_symbol__state: 0,
__zone_symbol__value: [NetworkError]
},
zone: <ref *1> Zone {
_parent: Zone {
  _parent: null,
  _name: '<root>',
  _properties: {},
  _zoneDelegate: [ZoneDelegate]
},
_name: 'angular',
_properties: { isAngularZone: true },
_zoneDelegate: <ref *2> ZoneDelegate {
  _taskCounts: [Object],
  zone: [Circular *1],
  _parentDelegate: [ZoneDelegate],
  _forkZS: null,
  _forkDlgt: null,
  _forkCurrZone: [Zone],
  _interceptZS: null,
  _interceptDlgt: null,
  _interceptCurrZone: [Zone],
  _invokeZS: [Object],
  _invokeDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
  _invokeCurrZone: [Circular *1],
  _handleErrorZS: [Object],
  _handleErrorDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
  _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular *1],
  _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
  _scheduleTaskDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
  _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
  _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
  _invokeTaskDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
  _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
  _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
source: 'Promise.then',
data: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
  __zone_symbol__state: 0,
  __zone_symbol__value: [NetworkError]
},
scheduleFn: undefined,
cancelFn: undefined,
callback: [Function (anonymous)],
invoke: [Function (anonymous)]
}
}
Error
ERROR [NetworkError]
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error
at resolvePromise (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:1016:31)
at resolvePromise (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:973:17)
at D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:1077:17
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:587:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server\main.js:84552:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:586:60)
at Zone.runTask (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:359:47)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:765:35)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:666:21)
at Server.ZoneTask.invoke (D:\Tecnogalre\tt\app2\dist\server.js:651:48) {
rejection: [NetworkError],
promise: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
__zone_symbol__state: 0,
__zone_symbol__value: [NetworkError]
},
zone: <ref *1> Zone {
_parent: Zone {
  _parent: null,
  _name: '<root>',
  _properties: {},
  _zoneDelegate: [ZoneDelegate]
},
_name: 'angular',
_properties: { isAngularZone: true },
_zoneDelegate: <ref *2> ZoneDelegate {
  _taskCounts: [Object],
  zone: [Circular *1],
  _parentDelegate: [ZoneDelegate],
  _forkZS: null,
  _forkDlgt: null,
  _forkCurrZone: [Zone],
  _interceptZS: null,
  _interceptDlgt: null,
  _interceptCurrZone: [Zone],
  _invokeZS: [Object],
  _invokeDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
  _invokeCurrZone: [Circular *1],
  _handleErrorZS: [Object],
  _handleErrorDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
  _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular *1],
  _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
  _scheduleTaskDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
  _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
  _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
  _invokeTaskDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
  _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
  _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
  _cancelTaskDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
  _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1],
  _hasTaskZS: [Object],
  _hasTaskDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
  _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular *2],
  _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular *1]
}
},
task: ZoneTask {
_zone: <ref *1> Zone {
  _parent: [Zone],
  _name: 'angular',
  _properties: [Object],
  _zoneDelegate: [ZoneDelegate]
},
runCount: 0,
_zoneDelegates: null,
_state: 'notScheduled',
type: 'microTask',
source: 'Promise.then',
data: ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
  __zone_symbol__state: 0,
  __zone_symbol__value: [NetworkError]
},
scheduleFn: undefined,
cancelFn: undefined,
callback: [Function (anonymous)],
invoke: [Function (anonymous)]
}
}
Error
```

Can anyone suggest how can identify the root cause of the below error? Because it's a more generic error and I don't have any idea to look at any specific thing due to this generic error. Any help will be much appreciated as I am trying to resolve this for a long today.

Below is my server.ts code

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'localstorage-polyfill';
import 'sessionstorage-polyfill';
import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';


// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser(); 
global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
global['sessionStorage'] = sessionStorage;
global['document'] = mock.getDocument();
global['window'] = mock.getWindow(); 

//import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built 
Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, 
ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = 
require('./dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ 
https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express- 
engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
]
}));



app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

 // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
 // Serve static files from /browser
 app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
    maxAge: '1y'
 }));

 // All regular routes use the Universal engine
 app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
 });






// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on 
http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Is this your server main in `angular.json`? Can you include your `main.server.ts` too pls?